# NetBeans пропадает курсор при сворачивании

Tags: windows, netbeans

Если переключиться из IDE NetBeans в другое приложение (Alt-Tab), то постоянно приходиться мышкой снова курсор активировать на строке.

Как решить проблему? Чтобы сворачивать и разворачивать и курсор постоянно мышкой не активировать его на строке. Нашел мини подход - 2 раза ESC нажимать. Есть ли другое решение?

Answer (score 1):

1. Открываем Диспетчер задач.
2. Находим процесс "NetBeans".
3. Ставим приоритет "В режиме реального времени"